# VXFS (veritas) File system filling up - except it's not

Tags: filesystems, solaris, mount, disk-space-utilization, veritas

I have a Solaris 10 server which is reporting that a file system is filling up:

```
# df -h /opt/CSCObac/var
Filesystem             size   used  avail capacity  Mounted on
/dev/vx/dsk/RDU-VAR-DG/RDU-VAR-VOL

# df -F vxfs /opt/CSCObac/var/
/opt/CSCObac/var   (/dev/vx/dsk/RDU-VAR-DG/RDU-VAR-VOL): 4469796 blocks   558723 files

# df -h | fgrep '/opt/'
/dev/vx/dsk/RDU-APP-DG/RDU-APP-VOL    68G   547M    63G     1%    /opt/CSCObac
/dev/vx/dsk/RDU-VAR-DG/RDU-VAR-VOL   134G   132G   2.0G    99%    /opt/CSCObac/var
/dev/vx/dsk/RDU-LOG-DG/RDU-LOG-VOL   134G   5.2G   121G     5%    /opt/CSCObac/var/rdu
```

Except there are no files on the filesystem which occupy 100G+, df reports it's not out of free blocks, and there's no lack of free inodes either:

```
# du -sh /opt/CSCObac/var
 5.1G   /opt/CSCObac/var
                   134G   132G   2.0G    99%    /opt/CSCObac/var

# df -g /opt/CSCObac/var/
/opt/CSCObac/var   (/dev/vx/dsk/RDU-VAR-DG/RDU-VAR-VOL):     8192 block size          1024 frag size  
280938496 total blocks    4469536 free blocks  4190192 available             558720 total files
558691 free files     74450896 filesys id  
vxfs fstype       0x00000004 flag             255 filename length
```

Also, no open file descriptors:

```
# lsof /opt/CSCObac/var/
#
```

This is a vxfs filesystem, see below for volume and size configurations:

```
# fstyp -v /dev/vx/dsk/RDU-VAR-DG/RDU-VAR-VOL
vxfs
magic a501fcf5  version 7  ctime November 15, 2013  2:15:55 PM CET
logstart 0  logend 0
bsize  1024 size  140469248 dsize  0  ninode 140469248  nau 0
defiextsize 0  ilbsize 0  immedlen 96  ndaddr 10
aufirst 0  emap 0  imap 0  iextop 0  istart 0
bstart 0  femap 0  fimap 0  fiextop 0  fistart 0  fbstart 0
nindir 2048  aulen 32768  auimlen 0  auemlen 8
auilen 0  aupad 0  aublocks 32768  maxtier 15
inopb 4  inopau 0  ndiripau 0  iaddrlen 8 bshift 10
inoshift 2  bmask fffffc00  boffmask 3ff  checksum f790321b
oltext1 32  oltext2 1282  oltsize 1  checksum2 0
free 2234899  ifree 0
efree  5 9 7 2 3 5 4 4 2 0 3 1 2 3 2 0 1 2 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 

# vxlist disk | grep 'VAR'
disk disk_4     RDU-VAR-DG01   RDU-VAR-DG     133.96g   608.00k imported
disk disk_8     RDU-VAR-DG02   RDU-VAR-DG     133.96g   608.00k imported

# vxlist vol RDU-VAR-VOL
Volume:  RDU-VAR-VOL
GUID:               {0de33acc-1dd2-11b2-a8f9-00212800c1e0}
Disk Group:         name=RDU-VAR-DG id=1384520670.51.rdu2a
Host:               rdu2a
Size:               133.9g
Type:               fsgen
Status:             healthy
Layout:             concat-mirror
NMirrors:           2
Read Policy:        SELECT
Flags:              open writeback
Device Path:        /dev/vx/dsk/RDU-VAR-DG/RDU-VAR-VOL
Permissions:        user=root group=root mode=0600

filesystem
TY   FSTYPE     %USED VSET   MOUNT-POINT
fs   vxfs         98% -      /opt/CSCObac/var

stats
TY   OPERATION       COUNT      BLOCKS   TIME(MSEC)
stat read          1160490     1731963      17538.5
stat write         3928639   294438233       7579.4

plexes
TY   NAME             TYPE     STATUS
plex RDU-VAR-VOL-03   simple   attached

# vxlist fs | fgrep 'VAR'
fs   var       vxfs       133.96g   2046.10m     99% /dev/vx/dsk/RDU-VAR-DG/RDU-VAR-VOL   /opt/CSCObac/var

# vxassist -g RDU-VAR-DG -p maxgrow RDU-VAR-VOL
VxVM vxassist ERROR V-5-1-1178 Volume RDU-VAR-VOL cannot be extend within the given constraints

# fsadm -D /opt/CSCObac/var/ 

  Directory Fragmentation Report
             Dirs        Total      Immed    Immeds   Dirs to   Blocks to
             Searched    Blocks     Dirs     to Add   Reduce    Reduce
  total            11         3         8         0         0           0
```

What could be filling up my filesystem beyond inodes, blocks and file descriptors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some lenghty troubleshooting with our support vendor, we found the solution.
There was a process running that was started before the mounting of the vxfs filesystems.
This process was writing data to /opt/CSCObac/var/rdu which is a nested directory of the /opt/CSCObac/var/ mountpoint.
After killing this process, the disk usage was back to the expected 1%
The OS could not report back on contents of this directory as the rdu mountpoint obscures it.
The long running process started writing to a file in this directory mountpoint before the filesystem was mounted, which explains why it was increasing in size without seeing an increase in the visible files within the directory.